Sci-fi scenario: Is it possible to detect and either broadcast over or otherwise block satellite comms to and from a geographic area that you control?
Near future science fiction. An authoritarian regime is trying to control its newly dominated population. Dissidents have satellite (30MHz to 60Ghz) phones and satellites are still under the control of other states. I want to make it hard for dissidents to have much bandwidth.

If you find out how to do it, there are several rich and powerful gentlemen in this world who would very much like to have a business discussion with you.

Thanks, folks all responses have been helpful - but I think given my fictional geopolitical constraints, authoritarians using drone-based IMSI catchers to location detect ground based sat transmissions should work to force my protagonists in enemy territory to have spread spectrum bandwidth limited transmission time so they only use short burst transmissions and have to move after transmitting. Thanks to all!


Jamming.
Consider the real-world problems of GPS spoofing. There are relatively small and low-powered transmitters and receivers in orbit, relatively small ones in the portable phones, and large and powerful jammers on Earth. Guess who wins if the satphone is close to the jammer ...

Detection and arrest.
Drones with receivers and direction finders circle over the city. If they detect a satphone transmitting, they alert the cops (plus other drones to triangulate). Users must never transmit from their home, arrange for sentries and getaway plans while they transmit from a public park or the like, and above all keep their transmissions short.

Auditing all devices.
Look at what North Korea does to control smartphone use. The dissidents have some smartphones, but they do not dare to connect them to any device which they carry openly, because all open devices check file signatures of anything they come into contact with. The problem, then, is to get data into the satphone other than by typing it into an air gapped device. Typing is decidedly low-bandwidth.



Jamming won't work really, you'll have to jam a VERY wide spectrum (60 GHz mind you) against a VERY narrow broadband signal (down to 1kHz bandwidth but it might be a long downlink transmission). Satellites (even civilian) use frequency change algorithms to avoid intentional or unintentional jamming already. Jamming an uplink is a whole lot harder, as you don't also know where is the transmitter. The two other activities would help though.

There’s a big smuggling operation that daily brings USB keys full of Internet content into and out of North Korea. It’s stunning to me how much can be accomplished with “sneaker net” these days.

Most usually there is no need for any kind of technical solution.
In the real world companies such as SpaceX need a license in order to provide communications services in a country; in the vast majority of cases they would definitely not do it without a license.
The only exception is when a very powerful country such as the USA explicitly tells its companies to provide services in countries such as Iran or North Korea which are currently considered enemies.

What if SpaceX of that world belongs to "other states" mentioned in the question, or directly to the state which the territory has been taken from? This answer is invalid in general.

@Vesper: I don't understand your objection. A domestic telecommunications company can be simply ordered to stop providing services in a specific area. The telecommunications network knows very well where each active terminal is, because that's how the thing works; a domestic company is obligated to obey the orders of the Ministry of Telecommunications or whatever the authority is called. Suspending communications services in specific geographical regions is a perfectly normal request.

I mean the target zone is conquered, and the remaining resistance is not civilian. Who would turn military satellites on foreign demand? Who would cede a territory without first attempting to defend it by force, if they are able? There is a possibility that the country whose territory got occupied has satellites above that territory which are used to coordinate the leftover resistance - will they turn them off? Take current Russia-Ukraine conflict, and conquered regions in there as an example.

A domestic telecom company will comply to orders of the government, sure, but here the company that provides satcom service might be second party or third party; and that third party could be like "you both are too weak to oppose me, and I will still provide service for either side, money doesn't smell". the second party would just say a big no to that government's demand, as it's assumed they are at war.

Much bandwidth? 110bps is enough
Count dissidents as foreign spies, consider that they only need to transmit (not receive) only a few bits of information per assigned task, and you'll understand that they might not need to talk to each other to coordinate, all data might be broadcast downwards from satellites at unknown frequency, unknown time and unknown bandwidth; satcom receiving could be performed by a civilian gadget if some common protocols would be used, and software designed for spies might mimic common activities to avoid detection by authorities. Privacy vs counter-espionage, that kind of difficulty. Transmission via satellites might be performed in a very short burst, largely unavailable for detection, although it should use specialized hardware. Oppression, since this is a conquered land, is required for ANY counter-espionage measures.
There is no technical-only solution
Assuming that those dissidents have access to hardware of arbitrary complexity that's available for at least someone in the world, there is always a way to avoid detection, jamming, interception and spoofing attempted by the local government. Against jamming you use frequency shift and lowering bandwidth, against detection you use phased lattice antennae that have a very narrow transmission diagram, burst transmission, passive counter-detection and local network-based proxy or similar service, against interception and spoofing you use encryption and supporting mechanisms that protect against attacks on a crypto-based data channel. From technical methods, detection-based approach is the best to actually succeed, say an aerial drone has the best chance to get hit by the main transmitting ray of a dissident's communication, revealing his location; there are still countermeasures against constant surveillance, but it belongs to cyber-warfare and is usually classified.
Organizational solutions are possible
First, limit the complexity of hardware available to be used by local civilians. Of course, spec ops and oter governmental departments should be exempt, as well as there might be some licensed use of certain devices by known entities, but this would cut down the majority of opportunities for those dissidents to obtain the equipment. If they already have enough, issue raids across population in any region where a transmission was detected somehow (as you cannot completely avoid detection if you transmit data), withdraw any device not allowed to civilians or licensees and detain people involved. Raids are pretty hard to actually accomplish, especially if the transmission was detected from a vast forest, but since the target country is under oppression, you are allowed to make it a lot harder to move away from somewhere in case of local spy alert.
Second, limit the civilians' ability to relocate. We're talking about a conquered area, so everyone is considered a possible enemy. Execute total control at any long-range travel sites as well as intercity traffic, random or thorough, this would also help to detect any spy hardware on their board, effectively limiting the ability of opposing forces to quickly relocate, which in turn would allow smaller raids with the same efficiency vs spies. Add curfews or similar counter-mobility measures, add martial law enforced by army, after all you never know who is the spy and whether any active opposition in terms of army is still around.
Space-based warfare is an option
At its ultimate position, your authoritarian govt has an ability to execute actions against the "enemy" satellites themselves, starting from diplomatic measures like putting pressure on satellite owners to cause them to deny those dissidents service, ending with physical destruction of any uncontrolled satellite transmitting over the target territory. After all, "near future" might contain some measures against Kessler syndrome dominating the low planet orbit making it less destructive to whever is going to use space after it manifesting.

Seed clouds to create thick dense areas of cloud storm coverage. Albeit only temporary but clouds could be seeded daily to cause poor reception until reflective dome built to bounce satellite away from special designated no sat phone areas. Until they figure out reflective dome technology they will employ regular search and seizure with roadblocks of search vehicles, search all luggage and search homes.  People that report known sat phone location or user get huge financial rewards or other benifits.

Hmm. Seeding clouds daily across the entire territory? It might be arbitrarily large based on the story. Assume they've just conquered a state the size of Russia - will you be able to maintain such cloud coverage for long enough, or ever? (Even smaller countries like France are not coverable)
